# How use lambda to sort in Python. When I tried to use lambda to sort str lists，I cant get the results that I want

Tags: python

There are two str lists:

```
list1 = ["Shogun","Tapioca Express","Burger King","KFC"]
list2 = ["KFC","Shogun","Burger King"]
```

I want to find the same elements in both lists and to sort them by their index sum.  Here is my code:

```
def findRestaurant(self, list1: List[str], list2: List[str]) -> List[str]:
    merge = list(set(list1) & set(list2))
    if len(merge) == 1:
        return merge
    merge.sort(key=lambda x: (list1.index(x) + list2.index(x)))
    return merge
```

it will output: `["Shogun","KFC","Burger King"]`
but if I want get `merge[0]` in the end, it will output:`["S","h","o","g","u","n"]` is not `["Shogun"]`, I don't understand why?

Comment: Cannot reprodue that. Output is `['Shogun', 'KFC', 'Burger King']`

Comment: Please post the code you're having problems with instead of a vague description of it.

Comment: There is a problem that is when I output sorted merge[0], it will output ["S","h","o","g","u","n"] is not ["Shogun"] that I want get if ['Shogun', 'KFC', 'Burger King'] is sorted merge.

Answer (score 0):

Does this what you want?

```py
 $ ipython
Python 3.8.1 (default, Dec 30 2019, 04:38:13)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.26.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: list1 = ["Shogun","Tapioca Express","Burger King","KFC"]

In [2]: list2 = ["KFC","Shogun","Burger King"]

In [3]: merge = sorted(set(list1) & set(list2), key=lambda x: list1.index(x) + list2.index(x))

In [4]: print(merge)
['Shogun', 'KFC', 'Burger King']

In [5]: sorted(set(list1) & set(list2), key=lambda x: list1.index(x) + list2.index(x), reverse=True)
Out[5]: ['Burger King', 'KFC', 'Shogun']

In [6]: print(merge[0])
Shogun
```

Comment: yeah! But there is a problem that is when I output sorted merge[0], it will output ["S","h","o","g","u","n"] is not ["Shogun"] that I want get if ['Shogun', 'KFC', 'Burger King'] is sorted merge.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to reverse the order？ try the keyword -> reverse

Comment: I  sort merge according index sum